# Multithreading wsgi not working

Tags: python, multithreading, wsgi

I have a mod_wsgi python application and when multiple users login to web portal, it seems to mix usernames.

```
def application(environ, start_response):
       username = None
       if "REMOTE_USER" in environ and environ["REMOTE_USER"]:
              username = environ["REMOTE_USER"]

        if ws_butt.lower()=='submit':
              return check_admin_params(environ,start_response,action,username)

def check_admin_params(environ,start_response,action,username):
       if action=="something":
          #do something
       else:
           return error_html(environ,start_response,username)
```

and I pass this "username" to all the functions to do certain things. It seems like if multiple users are logging in at the same time or randomly, getting mixed username. Is it not doing multithreading or Am I missing something?

```
configuration as WSGIDaemonProcess threads=25
```

How to make it synchronized that the session remains for the single user throughout?

Comment: You need to show exactly how you are passing this username to "all the functions".

Comment: added to the question..